# Django templates: block tag

Tags: html, django, django-templates, block

listTemp.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>{% block h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1>
  <style type="text/css">
         a:link {color: black;}      /* unvisited link */
         a:visited {color: black;}   /* visited link */
         a:hover {color: black;}     /* mouse over link */
         a:active {color: black;}    /* selected link */
  </style>
  {% if list_list %}
    {% for x in list_list %}
    <a href="{% url '{% block modelName %}{% endblock %}-detail' {% block modelName %}{% endblock %}.pk %}" style="border:1px solid black;padding:5px;margin-left:40px;margin-bottom:20px"><strong>Name:</strong> {% block modelName %}{% endblock %}.firstName } </a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <p>{% block modelName %}{% endblock %} database is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

client_list.html

```
{% extends "listTemp.html" %}
{% block h1 %}Clients{% endblock %}
{% block modelName %}client{% endblock %}
```

This is my first Django project and my first time working with HTML so my bad if it is obvious. I know what I have above is incorrect but how can I implement it? I have listviews and detail views for many models and they all have the exact same layout and the only difference in the files is the model name such as `client.firstName` and `url 'client-detail'` vs `contractor.firstName` and `url 'contractor-detail'`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I changed it so it works, but ran into an error with it in the process. I want to use this same template for many views, where some of them use child models.

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1></h1>
  <style type="text/css">
         a:link {color: black;}      /* unvisited link */
         a:visited {color: black;}   /* visited link */
         a:hover {color: black;}     /* mouse over link */
         a:active {color: black;}    /* selected link */
  </style>
  {% if object_list %}
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"style="border:1px solid black;padding:5px;margin-left:40px;margin-bottom:20px"><strong>Name:</strong> {{ object.firstName }} {{ object.lastName }} <strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Zone:</strong> {{ object.zipCode }} <strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Number:</strong> {{ object.phoneNumber }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <p>database is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I wanted to use this template for many separate views as I said, and it works for that, but three of my views are childs of object so for some I need to call `{{ object.parent.lastName }}` Static version: `{{ client.estimate.lastName }}` (estimate is a child of client). How can I do handle this within a single template?

I would also like to replace `<h1>{% block h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1>` with `<h1>object.class_name</h1>` but can't figure out how to genericly access object outside of the for loop. (class_name is a model function that returns the name of the model)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to use the same names as the model name in your template context. If you are using class-based views, for example, it is always `object_list` by default.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, can you replace `{% url 'x-detail'`  from listTemp.html and ` {% block modelName %}client{% endblock %}` from client_list.html with what they should look like? Or If I understood you correctly then I can use the listTemp.html template only and delete the client_list.html template since I can use the abstract/dynamic model name in listTemp.html and just set that template for all list views?  It would be very appreciated.

Comment: What I meant was that you can have a single template and reuse it from multiple views if all views pass the object list in the same context variable.

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand now. So what would the new version of  `{% url 'x-detail'` look like? would it be something like `{% url 'model-detail'`? I have a feeling I'm still incorrect.

Comment: @KameronSmith what Selcuk means here is that the name of the variable passed by CBV is independant of the model class (`object_list`), so you can simply loop over that as you need `{% for object in object_list %} {{ object.some_field }} {% endfor %}`. As for your url you can also pass the url name from the view in the context so you can reverse using that. Or better yet simply add a method to your model that will return the reversed url, a commonly used one being `get_absolute_url`